# Use variable on Sql Select

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT @z := ticketing_ticket.id_ticket_category as id, ticketing_ticket.email,
    CONCAT(
          TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date_create,date_close) , ' jours '
    ) AS 'temps de traitement '
    FROM ticketing_ticket 
    WHERE DATE(date_close) = CURDATE()
) AS X
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(T2.label SEPARATOR ';') AS 'Domaines', @z as id
    FROM (
        SELECT @r AS _id,
             (SELECT @r := id_parent 
              FROM ticketing_category 
              WHERE id_category = _id) AS parent_id,
              @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
        FROM ( SELECT @r :=@z , @l := 0) vars
        CROSS JOIN ticketing_category m
        WHERE @r <> 0
    ) T1
    JOIN ticketing_category T2
        ON T1._id = T2.id_category
) AS Y;
```

Output:

```
+----+------------------+----------+-----------------------------+----+
| ID |       EMAIL      | DURATION |           DOMAINS           | ID |
+----+------------------+----------+-----------------------------+----+
| 35 |  p.p@yopmail.com | 65 jours | Elec_Domain;Help_Sub_Domain | 38 |
+----+------------------+----------+-----------------------------+----+
| 36 | test@yopmail.com | 63 jours | Elec_Domain;Help_Sub_Domain | 38 |
+----+------------------+----------+-----------------------------+----+
| 28 |  admin@admin.com | 29 jours | Elec_Domain;Help_Sub_Domain | 38 |
+----+------------------+----------+-----------------------------+----+
| 38 |   test@test.com  | 21 jours | Elec_Domain;Help_Sub_Domain | 38 |
+----+------------------+----------+-----------------------------+----+
| 38 |   test@test.com  | 21 jours | Elec_Domain;Help_Sub_Domain | 38 |
+----+------------------+----------+-----------------------------+----+
```

My problem is i want to use the `id` on my second `sub-select` but on the output is the same `id`.
What's wrong on my request ?

Comment: What would be the desired result?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I would like to reuse the id of my first select in my sub-select. I have the impression that the variable @z always keeps the same value

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired result. You are doing a cross join and @z is assigned at the first subselect. A cross join operation will cross each row from the first table with all rows of the second table only then it will get the next row from the first table and hence reassign the value of @z. Instead of show what you have, show us what you need, it would be a lot easier to understand and help you out.